# $ \sum_{k=0}^t\, {k \choose a}{b \choose k}\,y^{b-k}\,x^{k-a}\,=\,{b \choose a}{(y+x)}^{b-a} $

Tags: combinatorics

How to prove that, for every natural numbers like $t$, the following relation holds:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^t\, {k \choose a}{b \choose k}\,y^{b-k}\,x^{k-a}\,=\,{b \choose a}{(y+x)}^{b-a}
$$
where $0 \leq a,b\leq t-1$.  Thanks for any suggestion.

*Edit(1):* Based on the @callculus comment. For fixed values of $a,b,x,y$, I checkd with Maple that the equation holds  for every value of $t\in \Bbb{N}$ and $0 \leq a,b\leq t-1$.

Comment: May be there is a typo, but for $t = 0$ we have $\binom{0}{a}\binom{b}{0}y^{b}x^{-a} = \binom{b}{a}(y + x)^{b - a}$ that is not true for $a = b = x = y = 1$ or almost any other values of $a, b, x, y$.

Comment: @Smylic $t$ is a natural numbers.

Comment: Number $0$ is natural (see ISO 80000-2:2009 etc.), but anyhow for $t = 1$ we have $\binom{0}{a}\binom{b}{0}y^{b}x^{-a} + \binom{1}{a}\binom{b}{1}y^{b - 1}x^{1 - a} = \binom{b}{a}(y + x)^{b - a}$, that is not true for $a = b = x = y = 2$ and almost any other values of $a, b, x, y$.

Comment: @Smylic You right, I edit question, Thanks

Comment: I would say that $t=b-a$. In my opinion if t appears on the LHS then it should appear on the RHS as well.

Comment: @callculus Is it possible to ask you to explain more, why do you write $t=b-a$? Thanks

Comment: @Amin235 It wouldn´t make sense since your exercise says that $t$ can be every natural number.

Comment: @callculus In fact, I checked the relation for various cases of natural number $t$ and $0\leq a,b \leq t-1$, with Maple and I saw that the relation holds.

Comment: @Amin235 Then include your work to your question. So you mean for **fixed**  values of  $a,b,x,y $ the equation holds for every value of $t \in\mathbb N$ and $a,b<t-1$ ?

Comment: @callculus yes holds. I edit question and add your note, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly note that $\binom{k}{a}\binom{b}{k} = \binom{b}{a}\binom{b - a}{k - a}$ for $k \ge a$. This is almost all. Also we need to see that $\binom{b}{k} = 0$ for all $k > b$ and $\binom{k}{a} = 0$ for all $k < a$, therefore
$$\sum_{k = 0}^t \binom{k}{a}\binom{b}{k}y^{b - k}x^{k - a} = \binom{b}{a}y^{b - a} \sum_{k = a}^b \binom{b - a}{k - a} y^{a - k}x^{k - a} \\
= \binom{b}{a}y^{b - a} \sum_{\ell = 0}^{b - a} \binom{b - a}{\ell} y^{-\ell}x^{\ell} = \binom{b}{a}y^{b - a} \left(1 + \frac{x}{y}\right)^{b - a} = \binom{b}{a}(y + x)^{b - a}$$
for all $b \ge a$.

If $b < a$ then all summands on the LHS are $0$ because either $k < a$ or $k > b$ for all $k$ and RSH is also $0$.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer.

Comment: Your answer is perfect,